# Finding Multi-Digit Integers in Python lines

Tags: python, python-3.x

Quick question (using Python 3.x)- I am writing a Python program that takes multiple lines of input, and then searches that input, finds all integers, sums them, and outputs the result. I'm kind of stumped as to the most efficient way to search through and find multi-digit integers- if a line contains 12, I want to find 12 and not [1,2]. Here's my code, unfinished:

```
def tally():
    #the first lines here are just to take multiple input
    text = []
    stripped_int = []
    stopkey = "END"
    while True:
        nextline = input("Input line, END to quit>")
        if nextline.strip() == stopkey:
            break
        text.append(nextline)
    #now we get into the processing
    #first, strip all non-digit characters
    for i in text:
        for x in i:
            if x.lower() in ['a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j','k','l','m','n','o','p','q','r','s','t','u','v','w','x','y','z','!',',','?']:
                pass
            else:
                stripped_int.append(x)
    print(stripped_int)

tally()
```

This prints me a list of all integers, but I'm stumped as to how to keep integers together. Any ideas?

Comment: Can a line have more than one number (e.g. `'1 2'`, which would add to 3)? Can numbers be combined with non-numbers (like `'foo42'`)? If either of these is allowed, I think you'll want to use regular expressions. `re.findall(r'\d+')` may be a good start.

Comment: Somebody else is actually answering the question but, from a general Python perspective, you could say `if x.isdigit()` - check out the string class helpdoc, there's a bunch of tests for character classes.  The 'string' class also has `string.digits`, `string.letters`, `string.printable` and so on.

Answer (score 5):

Using regular expressions:

```
import re

def tally(string):
    return map(int, re.findall(r'\b\d+\b', string))
```

Comment: short and sweet! And of course to get the sum you would just do `sum(tally(string))`

Comment: question: do you really need the `\b`s here? What would happen if they were removed?

Comment: @Claudiu: if you removed the `\b`'s then you would match on the string `abc123`.

Comment: Oh I think he would want the `123` to get included in that case. up to OP i suppose

Comment: I'm completely unfamiliar with regular expressions, but via a quick bit of Wikipedia I feel like this works in essence. How can I get it to print the output? I'm not sure how a map works as a variable.

Comment: @Weens: `map()` is a function that takes 2 arguments, the first being a function, and the second being an iterable of some sort. `map()` then applies the first argument to each element of the second argument. Since `re.findall()` returns a list of strings, `map(int, re.findall...)` converts each item in the list into an integer.